# Improve the solution to monkey grid puzzle

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> There is a monkey which can walk around on a planar grid. The monkey
>   can move one space at a time left, right, up or down. That is, from
>   (x, y) the monkey can go to (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), and (x,
>   y-1). Points where the sum of the digits of the absolute value of the
>   x coordinate plus the sum of the digits of the absolute value of the y
>   coordinate are lesser than or equal to 19 are accessible to the
>   monkey. For example, the point (59, 79) is inaccessible because 5 + 9
>   + 7 + 9 = 30, which is greater than 19. Another example: the point (-5, -7) is accessible because abs(-5) + abs(-7) = 5 + 7 = 12, which
>   is less than 19. How many points can the monkey access if it starts at
>   (0, 0), including (0, 0) itself?

I came up with the following brute force solution (pseudo code):

```
/*
legitPoints = {}; // all the allowed points that monkey can goto
list.push( Point(0,0) ); // start exploring from origin

while(!list.empty()){
 Point p = list.pop_front(); // remove point

 // if p has been seen before; ignore p => continue;
 // else mark it and proceed further

 if(legit(p){
 // since we are only exploring points in one quadrant, 
 // we don't need to check for -x direction and -y direction
 // hence explore the following: this is like Breadth First Search
  list.push(Point(p.x+1, p.y)); // explore x+1, y
  list.push(Point(p.x, p.y+1)); // explore x, y+1

  legitPoints.insert(p); // during insertion, ignore duplicates 
                         // (although no duplicates should come through after above check)
                         // count properly using multipliers
                         // Origin => count once x = 0 && y == 0 => mul : 1
                         // X axis => count twice x = 0 && y != 0 => mul : 2
                         // Y axis => count twice x != 0 && y = 0 => mul : 2
                         // All others => mul : 4
 }

 return legitPoints.count();
}
*/
```

This is a very brute force solution. One of the optimizations I used was to one scan one quadrant instead of looking at four. Another one was to ignore the points that we've already seen before.

However, looking at the final points, I was trying to find a pattern, perhaps a mathematical solution or a different approach that would be *better* than what I came up.

Any thoughts ?

PS: If you want, I can post the data somewhere. It is interesting to look at it with any one of the axis sorted.

First quadrant visual:
[image]

Comment: The output would be good to see. It might make it easier to see a pattern if it's there.

Comment: To me, this looks it could be mapped onto any graph algorithm that detects connectedness of a graph.

Comment: The data file has a lot of points. Any place where I can upload it ?

Comment: Looks somewhat related to the Sierpinsky and/or Pascal triangles... Perhaps there's a solution that has something to do with the related binomial series...

Comment: Another rather small optimization would be to realize that mathematically, the largest square region in which *all* points have a sum less than 19 is from (0, 0) to (18, 18), so you can start your search at the boundaries of this square.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your BFS solution seems perfectly fine, and I can't imagine it takes any more than a tiny fraction of a second to run.  Is there an actual question here?

Comment: Also your graph appears to be incorrect *(eg. `(99, y)` should only be on the graph if y = 1, 10, or 100)* **(Edit)** Oh I see, it is because you are using large diamonds as points.  You can change that in Excel, under the graph options.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft lots of other points, too. (19,19),(27,47), etc. I think the visual is just bad, though. It seems the dots used for points are much bigger than the actual points, so it all overlaps.

Comment: You can actually narrow it done to an eighth rather than just a quadrant. eg 0<x<y since if (a,b) is valid and connected then (b,a) is also valid and connected.

Comment: @Chris can you elaborate on that ? What would be the extents of this quadrant ?

Comment: @brainydexter: Essentially the idea is to notice that the pattern you get is a reflection in the line x=y. So essentially I'm saying divide your area into 8 pieces using th vertical cross and a diagonal cross and then you can just reflect the solution in any one of those quadrants to get all the solutions. Essentially given 2,1 is part of the solution then by reflection in x=y gives also that 1,2 is part of the solution. Reflect both of those two in the y axis gives -2,1 and -1,2 is a solution and reflect those in the x axis gives the last four components 2,-1; 1,-2; -2,-1; -1,-2.

Comment: Ah, I see....further optimized from the quadrant to octants...cool I'll give it a go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what the whole grid looks like as an image:

[image]

The black squares are inaccessible, white accessible, gray accessible and reachable by movement from the center. There's a 600x600 bounding box of black because the digits of 299 add to 20, so we only have to consider that.

This exercise is basically a "flood fill", with a shape which is just about the worst case possible for a flood fill. You can do the symmetry speedup if you like, though that's not really where the meat of the issue is--my solution runs in 160 ms without it (under 50ms with it).

The big speed wins are (1) do a line-filling flood so you don't have to put every point on the stack, and (2) manage your own stack instead of doing recursion. I built my stack as two dynamically-allocated vectors of ints (for x and y), and they grow to about 16k, so building whole stack frames that deep would definitely be a huge loss.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this: "The big speed wins are (1) do a line-filling flood so you don't have to put every point on the stack, and (2) manage your own stack instead of doing recursion." I didn't understand the part, in how is this a flood fill...

Comment: Google "flood fill" and check out the methods. I don't want to do your project for you. It's clearly the same thing; I could have made this image exactly by doing it in just black and white, loading it into GIMP and telling it to gray fill the center.

Comment: @Lee May be I am missing something, but what if i have (x,y) as (1000,2000) . There can be infinite such points. How do you say there is a bounding box?

Comment: @Lee are you referring to scan line flood fill algorithm ?

Comment: Yes, a scanline flood fill helps speed things up. The digits of 299 add to 20, so it doesn't matter what the other index is: (299, y) is a solid line of black, as are (x, 299), (-299, y) and (x, -299). These cross to form a solid black border. Yes, there are white cells outside this border, but they can never be reached by movement.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I reviewed the scanline flood fill algorithm again, and isn't it the same for what I've done (just that I've done it for the first quadrant) ? My seed point is the origin. I then happen to check adjacent points, I color them(mark them good) and use those points as future seed points. Also, Id have to check for every point since (as you also saw) the shape has holes in it.

Comment: I don't want to give you my whole solution, but my inner loop is something like this:

    while (<stack is not empty>) {
        <pop x, y>;
        line = gp->data + (y * gp->size);
        for (xx = x;    0xFF == line[xx];   ++xx) {
            line[xx] = 0x88;
            push(gp, xx, y-1);
            push(gp, xx, y+1);
        }
        for (xx = x-1;  0xFF == line[xx];   --xx) {
            line[xx] = 0x88;
            push(gp, xx, y-1);
            push(gp, xx, y+1);
        }
    }

Comment: Sure, I'm not looking for a solution. I'm interested in learning the approach. From the snippet you posted, I understand that for a given point <x,y> (most likely seed in first run), you push x, y+1 and y-1 in both right and left direction, and mark them as gray (0x88). There are some missing pieces here though. I think you find the polygon extents first and that defines the border(0x0). So, this check (0xFF == line[xx]) will stop when it has reached the borders. But, how will it cover the case for holes within this polygon ?

Comment: Also, can you comment a bit on the data structure gp and line here.

Comment: `y+1` and `y-1` are up and down, not right and left. `line` is simply the line of pixels at `y`, which are filled by the loop without pushing, that's the "scanline" speedup. "Holes" aren't supposed to be filled, that's the whole point! You're supposed to count the cells that can be reached by the monkey moving from the start, and "holes" can't be reached. `gp` is just my structure to hold all the challenge data.

Comment: True, I was impling right and left by ++xx and --xx. Can we continue the discussion here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35269/improving-monkeygrid-solution

Comment: I have no interest in chat. If you haven't solved this yet with all of the answers here, I don't think wasting any more of my time will help.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking for the ideal solution I had something similar. For each point the monkey is, I added the next 4 possibilities to a list and did the same for the next four recursively only if they had not been visited. This can be also done with multiprocessing to speed up the process.

Comment: I actually considered the first quadrant and mirrored it across, so you don't need to check for 4 possibilities, only 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, more like a BFS:

```
int DigitSum(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;

    num = (num >= 0) ? num : -num;
    while(num) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

struct Point {
    int x,y;
    Point(): x(0), y(0) {}
    Point(int x1, int y1): x(x1), y(y1) {}

    friend bool operator<(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    {
        if (p1.x < p2.x) {
            return true;
        } else if (p1.x == p2.x) {
            return (p1.y < p2.y);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

void neighbor(vector<Point>& n, const Point& p)
{
    if (n.size() < 4) n.resize(4);

    n[0] = Point(p.x-1, p.y);
    n[1] = Point(p.x+1, p.y);
    n[2] = Point(p.x, p.y-1);
    n[3] = Point(p.x, p.y+1);
}

int numMoves(const Point& start)
{
    map<Point, bool> m;
    queue<Point> q;
    int count = 0;
    vector<Point> neigh;

    q.push(start);
    m[start] = true;
    while (! q.empty()) {
        Point c = q.front();
        neighbor(neigh, c);
        for (auto p: neigh) {
            if ((!m[p]) && (DigitSum(p.x) + DigitSum(p.y) <= 19)) {
                count++;
                m[p] = true;
                q.push(p);
            }
        }
        q.pop();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how different this may be from brainydexter's idea... roaming the one quadrant, I instituted a single array hash `(index = 299 * y + x)` and built the result with another array, each index storing only the points that expand from its previous index, for example:

```
first iteration, result = [[(0,0)]]
second iteration, result = [[(0,0)],[(0,1),(1,0)]]
...
```

On an old IBM Thinkpad in JavaScript, the speed seemed to vary from 35-120 milliseconds ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/groovy/6FzdE/)).

Comment: I briefly glanced and it looks similar to what I am doing. PS: The visual looks good :)

Comment: indeed. From what I can gather, a flood fill must also check for points already marked (i.e., is the node already the target-color) so I'm not sure how the efficiencies exactly compare.